# How would I use an If Statement from a userform where if the cell matches another cell it would add the results to a specific field / row?

Tags: excel, vba

The majority of my code is working correctly however, when I move onto validation form the userform to excel it isn't working correctly.  I am using a form that allows the user to enter in a job number in column AA and Quantity in Column AC.  I am keeping a list of jobs in column A.  When the user uses the button it will auto fill columns AA thru AD I am looking for after this is done it will check to see if the job number exists in column A and if it does then in the same row in Column D it would add the quantity that was just entered.  In the background I have a piece of code that will auto calculate and increase in column D

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
whichSheet = PartNoTxtBox.Value
If whichSheet = "" Then
MsgBox "You didn't specify a Part Number"
Exit Sub
End If
Worksheets(whichSheet).Activate
    If Me.PartNoTxtBox = "" Then GoTo MoreInfo
    If Me.AddJobNoTxtBox = "" Then GoTo MoreInfo
    If Me.AddShipperNoTxtBox = "" Then GoTo MoreInfo
    If Me.AddQtyTxtBox = "" Then GoTo MoreInfo
    If Me.AddDate = "" Then GoTo MoreInfo
''LastRow
    eRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "AA").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 27).Row
        Cells(eRow, 27) = AddJobNoTxtBox.Text
        Cells(eRow, 28) = AddShipperNoTxtBox.Text
        Cells(eRow, 29) = AddQtyTxtBox.Text
        Cells(eRow, 30) = AddDate.Text
       If AddJobNoTxtBox.Value = Cells(eRow, 1) Then
         Cells(eRow, 4) = AddQtyTxtBox.Text
        End If
 Unload UserForm1
Exit Sub
MoreInfo:
    MsgBox "More information required."

End Sub
```

The issue is located at the If AddJobNoTxtBox.Value=Cells...
any direction would be helpful.

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: When it comes to the If statement it isn't adding the value from AddQtyTxtBox to column D based on the Job Number

Comment: Do you have data in `Column AA`?

Comment: Yes I have data showing in column AA